# How to gray out WPF circle button when it is disabled?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the whole botton to be grayed:
[image]

Here is my code:

```xaml
<Button Width="120" Cursor="Hand" 
            Name="btnPrintCard"
            Click="btnPrintCard_Click"
            Height="120" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
    <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="Green">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome print}" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Print</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Start printing card</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

*I already found the topic about graying out the button image but in my case I used the icon which I don't know how to make it the same.

Comment: @AmitJoshi The green color comes from the Rectangle's Fill. The image is just a mask.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want to get super fancy, check out [`VisualStateManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx), use Manfred's answer for the simple easy way though.

Comment: Thanks all of you Guys for commenting here, it 's very useful for me as I 'm very new for WPF and this is also my first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```xml
<Rectangle Width="80" Height="80">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome print}" />
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    <Rectangle.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Make sure to remove `Fill="Green"` from your Rectangle because that would override the color set in the Style.

Since `IsEnabled` *inhertis* down the VisualTree the Rectangles `IsEnabled` will be `false` whenever it's parent (or any ancestor, like your button) is disabled.